# How to you set a table name to a correlation name in PHP for a SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a line of code in PHP, and this is probably a stupid question but I'm new to coding.  I get this error when I try to run my php page:

> "Error in query preparation/execution. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 1013 [code] => 1013 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The objects
>   "ACTION" and "action" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names.
>   Use correlation names to distinguish them. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The objects
>   "ACTION" and "action" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names.
>   Use correlation names to distinguish them. ) )"

My question is simply how do I use a correlation name for the table name?  I have a table called "action" and I am trying to write a statement that contains inner joins, so the database doesn't like that I'm trying to perform the `INNER JOIN ACTION` on my `action` table.. go figure!

I've tried to research it, but I keep finding complex examples of setting correlation names. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use unique aliases for each case where you use the `action` table. You did not show your query, but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ACTION a1
INNER JOIN ACTION a2 ON ...
```

This way, the intended use of each instance of the same table is clear to the query parser.